# how to get current year in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

i wanna do if year= current year, value = blank

```
LastYear(inflationrate) = IF(YEAR([measure])=YEAR(NOW()),"",CALCULATE(SUMX(Table,Table[inflation_rate]*[Last_Year])/100))
```

I can't get the date column into the year function, only measure is coming.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a measure, there is no row context, therefore it's not possible to directly specify Table[Column] but some function must be used to specify to specify what row is to be taken in the current filter context. For instance MAX can be used, so you can specify

```
LastYear(inflationrate) =
IF (
    YEAR (
        MAX ( Table[Date] )
    )
        = YEAR (
            NOW ()
        ),
    "",
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX (
            Table,
            Table[inflation_rate] * [Last_Year]
        ) / 100
    )
)
```